# MaxLength of column seems to be always -1 for the string fields in the datatable C#

Tags: c#

All my data table column fields from the stored procedure is string fields as like given below

```
    [Account Code] varchar(10),
    Filler1 varchar(5), 
    [Accounting Period] varchar(7),
    [Transaction Date] varchar(8),
    Filler2 varchar(2),
    [Record Type] varchar(1),
    [Source] varchar(2),
    [Journal No] varchar(5),
    [Journal Line] varchar(7)
```

Using the below code only I am picking the value from the SP to the dataset as given below

```
public DataSet InvoicesToSageExtractGoodsIn(string invoiceDateFrom)
{

    SqlConnection conn = null;
    DALFactory dalFactory = null;
    SqlDataAdapter da = null;

    try
    {
        DataSet dsInvoiceCustomer = new DataSet();
        dalFactory = new DALFactory();

        conn = new SqlConnection(dalFactory.ConnectionStringVI);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("prc_ReturnSageExtractGoodsIn", conn);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DALSystemTable dst = new DALSystemTable(this.dao);
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(dst.GetSystemConstant("CommandTimeOut"));

        SqlParameter param1 = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceDateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime);//VI-165
        param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param1.Value = invoiceDateFrom;                               

        DataSet dsInvoice = new DataSet("VisionInvoicing");
        DataTable dtInvoiceNos = new DataTable("tblSageExtractGoodsIn");

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        da.Fill(dsInvoice);

        dsInvoice.Tables[0].TableName = "tblGenerateInvoice";


        return dsInvoice;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new DatabaseException(ex.Message, ex);
    }

}
```

When I try to pick the `MaxLength` of the column (dtSAGEExtract.Columns[i].MaxLength) from that dataset table it always shows -1 value.

```
foreach (DataRow drExtract in dtSAGEExtract.Rows)
{
    int fieldCount = (dtSAGEExtract.Columns.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
    {
        int length = dtSAGEExtract.Columns[i].MaxLength;
        writer.Write(drExtract[i].ToString().PadRight(length));
    }

    writer.WriteLine();
}

writer.Close();
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is always showing -1 for all the fields?

Comment: varchar(2)?  varchar(1)?  I hope you aren't really using those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to add your `DataTable` to the `DataSet` to make it work after you created the `DataTable` because they are not connected in your example and filling the `DataSource` has no impact on the `DataTable` created in the next line so that you can use the additional schema information:

```
dsInvoice.Tables.Add(dtInvoiceNos);
```

then you need to call the [SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fillschema(v=vs.110).aspx) on your `SqlDataAdapter` to get more information from your database then just the data when using only the `Fill` method

```
da.FillSchema(dtInvoiceNos, SchemaType.Source);
da.Fill(dsInvoice);
```

The fill operations must be called after you added the table to the dataset.

Comment: Tired both of them still -1

Comment: I edited my answer and tested it and it worked now (in both cases Source/Mapped).

Answer (score 1):

It does not represent the MaxLength of DataTable column. It is not depend on database schema either. 
It return -1 because it is default value when you do not set anything.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then how can I get the column size...Suppose if a field is varchar(10),then i need to get the size =10

Answer (score 0):

Because you not fill schema to dataset.

Normaly -1 is default length of column.

You should use:

`da.FillSchema(dsInvoice, SchemaType.Mapped)`

UPDATE:

```
DataTable dtInvoiceNos = dsInvoice.Tables[0];
```

Please check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/229sz0y5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please try: DataTable firstTable = dsInvoice.Tables[0]; Please check my update